# epslatex visible box doesn't fit all of the info (axis names)

Tags: graphics, gnuplot, eps

i'm preparing a publication into Phys Rev E. 
they ask to use revtex. in revtex guidelines, they say that i should include eps files.

i already have all the plots made with latex symbols and formulas. so i just want to make a single plot.eps file out of each plot instead of eps+tex.

i used a keyword standalone. it worked partially. all the info is included however when i open the generated (latex plot.tex; dvips plot.tex) standalone plot.ps file i don't see the axis on the plot. they are truncated. if i open the plot.dvi file using xdvi and zoom out, i c the axis. so the frame is just smaller than a plot. is there an easy way to change the frame size or should i use ps terminal instead of epslatex?

Comment: i can't anser my own question but, i found that dvips just needs an option -E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[kirill_ignum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1643/kirill-igum) was able to answer his own question:

run `dvips` with the option `-E`